# Separate or combined ServiceStack services?

Tags: web-services, rest, servicestack

I want to have ServiceStack endpoints such as the following...

```
[RestService("/items/recent")]
[RestService("/items/recent/{Page}")]
[RestService("/items/popular")]
[RestService("/items/popular/{Page}")]
```

Since both would return a `List<Item>`, I'd love to be able to have both of these in the same `RestServiceBase` for easier code management. Is this possible? If so, how can I differentiate the request when it comes in to find whether it was a "recent" or "popular" request so that I can handle it appropriately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can have multiple REST-ful paths pointing to the same web service.

If you want to leave the paths as-is you can inspect the Request Path used to invoke the service via the HttpRequest, i.e:

```
var httpReq = base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>();
httpReq.PathInfo //or httpReq.RawUrl, httpReq.AbsoluteUri, etc.
```

The way you work out what type of request it is, is by looking at the populated Request DTO - but to distinguish between **/recent/** and **/popular/** you should store it in another Request DTO property and then inspect its values i.e.

```
[RestService("/items/{Type}")]
[RestService("/items/{Type}/{Page}")]
public class Items
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int? Page { get; set; }
}

public class ItemsService : ServiceBase<Items>
{
    public override object Run(Items request)
    {
        if (request.Type == "recent")
           if (!request.Page.HasValue) 
              //path 1
           else
              //path 2
        else if (request.Type == "popular")
           if (!request.Page.HasValue) 
              //path 3
           else
              //path 4
    }
}
```

This is also similar to this StackOverflow question:
[Need help on servicestack implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007232/need-help-on-servicestack-implementation)

Comment: Lovely! I knew you'd have a good answer. By the way, this service of mine is coming along insanely well! Basing it off the RedisStackOverflow example since it's very similar. Loving ServiceStack!

Comment: @robertmiles3 Awesome, glad to hear it :) IMO Redis-backed ServiceStack apps are bound to produce awesome UX - Don't forget to post a link of your app to the Google Group when you're done!